# Can't access data in email view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, smtp, laravel-blade

I have a problem with email's views with Laravel. This is how I send a mail:

```
$user = $bet->user; // A bet hasOne user. All is ok here

Mail::queue('emails.betWon', array('user' => $user), function($message) use ($user)
{
    $message->to($user->email)->subject('Tu as remporté un pari !');
});
```

This is my view `emails.betWon`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ var_dump($user) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the mail I get:

```
array (size=3)
  'timestamps' => boolean false
  'incrementing' => boolean true
  'exists' => boolean true
```

Which is not a User object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using Mail::queue you cannot send an object to the queue, as data is being serialized. You need to convert it to an array first.

change

```
$user = $bet->user;
```

to

```
$user = $bet->user->toArray();
```